# How to delete information from a hard drive, when the hard drive is too damaged to use?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I recently bought a hard drive, and after only a couple weeks it broke completely, to the point where I can't even log in to my computer. I want to mail it back to get a refund, but the problem is, there's some sensitive data on it. And just because I can't use it to log in doesn't mean the data couldn't be recovered. Maybe I'm being paranoid, but I don't like the idea of mailing out such valuable data to an unknown destination.

Since I can't even use it to log in, I can't delete this data the normal way. But I also don't want to shatter it to pieces, which will negate the refund.

Is there a way I can wipe the drive or reduce it to a completely non-recoverable state without logging on to a computer with it? I was contemplating just dropping it in water, or maybe using magnets.

Comment: Talk to the manufacturer of the hard drive. They usually have a way to resolve this. For example, they may accept you sending the hard drive to a destruction facility who will confirm to them that the drive was destroyed.

Comment: I doubt you will get a refund after dropping it in water, remove the hard drive and put it into a usb enclosure, connect it to another pc and erase the data.

Comment: Try dban but if it's to badly damaged even that might fail because of I/O errors

Comment: to login?  Are you sure the drive is messed up have you tried using a USB with a live OS to boot of and see if it mounts it?  What kind of drive is It I mean there is not a doubt that it won't kill over in a few weeks but it shouldn't it's rare occasions of whatever happened to it.  I would first try a live disc or USB then contact the manufacturer the company manufacturer will not look at your data they will try and maybe send it through a wipe statation they have setup that wipes however many drives at a time then grind it up somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I couldn't log in, I was able to reach the root shell. From there, I ran the Ubuntu `shred` command which replaced every bit of data with a random bit.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally if you can't log in on it you may still be able to access it as a slave drive to a working hard drive.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)